# How to print TeXForm running script?

Tags: printing, scripting

I've got a simple script which runs in bash some code - I want now to get an answer in TeX Form. If I would run Mathematica code inside the interpreter, it would be easy:

```
Mathematica 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2014 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= V=(m w^2x^2)/2                                                                                                                          

           2  2
        m w  x
Out[1]= -------
           2

In[2]:= TeXForm[V]                                                                                                                              

Out[2]//TeXForm= \frac{1}{2} m w^2 x^2
```

But when I want to run it like a bash script ( ./code.m ), I type something like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/math -script 

VO= (m w^2x^2)/2
Print[VO]
Print[TeXForm[VO]
```

I get:

```
(m*w^2*x^2)/2
TeXForm[(m*w^2*x^2)/2]
```

How to get proper TeXForm printing output?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your output, but I don't see how to change it using the `-script` option.  I've always used the `-run` option (which I learned oh so long ago [from Jens](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html)), and now I see that it is indeed different from the `-script` option.

I have 2 files, one is `code.m` that you have above (with the final closing bracket included), and another `code2.m`, which only has the Mathematica commands

```
VO= (m w^2x^2)/2
Print[VO]
Print[TeXForm[VO]]
```

I run this via the command `math -noprompt -run "<<code2.m; Exit[]; "`

Here is the difference between the two ways of running it,

[image]

And actually, it seems you don't even need to have a second file, you can just run the `code.m` that you have and it seems to ignore the first line as if it were a comment.